# Where is the /etc/login.conf file in Ubuntu 12.10 and latest?

Tags: command-line, login, sudo, login-screen

Where is the file for the general login for to configure it?

`/etc/login.conf` seems to be outdated in 12.10 ?

I want to adjust maximum number of login attempts. e.g. in sudo from 3 to 1.
same for kdm, gdm, lightdm and for command su.

Is there a general file for all login-queries?

Comment: Do you mean this file? `/var/lib/dpkg/info/login.conffiles`

Comment: If some answer has been useful for you, upvote it. Also you can [mark it as accepted](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer). So your question remains as answered. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no general file.

For `sudo`, this can be achieved with the `faillog` command. (see the man pages for info)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 13.04 I have `/etc/login.defs`. This file contains the following line:

```
LOGIN_RETRIES       5
```

This means that I have 5 attempts to login from a TTY.

If I modify the value to 1, then I have no login retries.

I'm not sure if this is what are you looking for, but I hope so.